# comma separator for datagridview textbox columns

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, controls

I need Currency TextBox in DataGridView , I search Internet and Find this solution [[^]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/9347456c-404d-45b4-8911-999419c94387)
But this is useful when dataGridView Cell Leave event,I need comma separator in textchange ,
However I write this source for this purpose :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt_edit = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (txt_edit != null)
            {

                txt_edit.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_edit_TextChanged);
            }
        }

        private void txt_edit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox) sender;

            string str = txt.Text;
            str = str.Replace(",", "");
            int len = str.Length;
            if (len > 3)
            {
                str = str.Insert(len - 3, ",");
                len = len - 3;
                while (len > 3)
                {
                    str = str.Insert(len - 3, ",");
                    len = len - 3;
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = str;
            dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
        }
```

when i run my program and input number this source work correctly for 3 first digit , until type fourth number cording this error:
[image]

why this error cording?
Is there a better way to solve the problem?
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = str;
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
```

With:

```
int selStartFromEnd = txt.Text.Length - txt.SelectionStart;
txt.TextChanged -= txt_edit_TextChanged;
txt.Text = str;
txt.TextChanged += txt_edit_TextChanged;
if (txt.Text.Length - selStartFromEnd >= 0)
    txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length - selStartFromEnd;
dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work....(Not 100% sure)

```
delegate void SetColumnIndex(); 
private void txt_edit_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 

 //.....
  dataGridView1.EndEdit(); 

  SetColumnIndex method = new SetColumnIndex(Mymethod); 
  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = str;
  dataGridView1..BeginInvoke(method);

         }         

 private void Mymethod()
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = myGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0];
            dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
        }
```